# Soapui - unable to create new project

Tags: soap, nullpointerexception, soapui, access-denied

I am getting Error loading(url):java.lang.nullpointer exception, after providing WSDL for creating a new SOAPUi project.

It is also saying that soapui-4.0.0.exe has been denied access to 169.185.231.98.

can someone help me with this?

Thanks,
Amir

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: Version 4.0.0?!?! Can you try a later version?